# Correctly reading HttpRequest body asynchronously in NetCore web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express

I am trying to get POST request body as `string` in C#. I wrote this:

```
    protected async Task<string> readBodyAsync(HttpRequest req)
    {
        // turns out this is always false...
        if(req.Body.CanSeek)
            req.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // string buffer
        string str = "";
        // I wouldn't expect to have to do this in 2017
        byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
        int offset = 0;
        int lastLen = 0;
        // On second iteration, CanRead is true but ReadAsync throws System.ArgumentException
        while ( req.Body.CanRead && (lastLen = await req.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, buffer.Length))!=0)
        {
            offset += lastLen;
            // This also adds all the \0 characters from the byte buffer, instead of treating like
            // normal C string
            str += System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
        // This never executes due to the System.ArgumentException
        return str;
    }
```

The issues:

- On second iteration, `req.Body.CanRead` is `true`, but calling read causes `System.ArgumentException`
- All is read on first iteration already. Not only that, `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString` adds all remaining zeroes from the buffer to the string.

I handle the request like this:

```
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        if(context.Request.Method.ToLower() == "post" && context.Request.Path.ToString().EndsWith("/ajax"))
        {
            string requestText = await readBodyAsync(context.Request);
            /// Parsing of the JSON in requestText should be here
               // but I can't get that text
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("{data: \"AJAX TEST\"}");
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World! And go away. Invalid request.");
        }  
    });
```

Answer (score 17):

```
    private async Task<string> StreamToStringAsync(HttpRequest request)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(request.Body))
        {
            return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there's a more elegant way that also works:

```
    protected async Task<string> readBodyAsync(HttpRequest req)
    {
        StreamReader r = new StreamReader(req.Body);
        return await r.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
```

Comment: `StreamReader` should be disposed after using it. Note that disposing the StreamReader will also close its underlying stream.

Answer (score -1):

```
var body = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

Comment: A `StreamReader` should be disposed after using it, and in essence this answer just repeats existing answers in worse form. The two year old answer by Timothy essentially provides the same information, but correctly disposes the stream reader.